# Automatically check or uncheck RecyclerView checkboxes with boolean values

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I need to check my recyclerview checkboxes automatically based on boolean values coming from POJO class. below is my class details.

**HealthStatusCheck.java**:

```
public class HealthStatusCheck {
private int id;
private int donorID;
private boolean q1;
private boolean q2;
private boolean q3;
private boolean q4;
private boolean q5;
private boolean q6;
private boolean q7;
private boolean q8;
private boolean q9;
private boolean q10;
private boolean q11;
private boolean q12;
private boolean q13;
private boolean q14;
private boolean q15;
private boolean q16;
private boolean q17;
private boolean q18;
private boolean q19;
private boolean q20;

public HealthStatusCheck() {}

public HealthStatusCheck(int id, int donorID, boolean q1, boolean q2, boolean q3, boolean q4, boolean q5, boolean q6,
                         boolean q7, boolean q8, boolean q9, boolean q10, boolean q11, boolean q12, boolean q13,
                         boolean q14, boolean q15, boolean q16, boolean q17, boolean q18, boolean q19, boolean q20) {
    this.id = id;
    this.donorID = donorID;
    this.q1 = q1;
    this.q2 = q2;
    this.q3 = q3;
    this.q4 = q4;
    this.q5 = q5;
    this.q6 = q6;
    this.q7 = q7;
    this.q8 = q8;
    this.q9 = q9;
    this.q10 = q10;
    this.q11 = q11;
    this.q12 = q12;
    this.q13 = q13;
    this.q14 = q14;
    this.q15 = q15;
    this.q16 = q16;
    this.q17 = q17;
    this.q18 = q18;
    this.q19 = q19;
    this.q20 = q20;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getDonorID() {
    return donorID;
}

public void setDonorID(int donorID) {
    this.donorID = donorID;
}

public boolean isQ1() {
    return q1;
}

public void setQ1(boolean q1) {
    this.q1 = q1;
}

public boolean isQ2() {
    return q2;
}

public void setQ2(boolean q2) {
    this.q2 = q2;
}

public boolean isQ3() {
    return q3;
}

public void setQ3(boolean q3) {
    this.q3 = q3;
}

public boolean isQ4() {
    return q4;
}

public void setQ4(boolean q4) {
    this.q4 = q4;
}

public boolean isQ5() {
    return q5;
}

public void setQ5(boolean q5) {
    this.q5 = q5;
}

public boolean isQ6() {
    return q6;
}

public void setQ6(boolean q6) {
    this.q6 = q6;
}

public boolean isQ7() {
    return q7;
}

public void setQ7(boolean q7) {
    this.q7 = q7;
}

public boolean isQ8() {
    return q8;
}

public void setQ8(boolean q8) {
    this.q8 = q8;
}

public boolean isQ9() {
    return q9;
}

public void setQ9(boolean q9) {
    this.q9 = q9;
}

public boolean isQ10() {
    return q10;
}

public void setQ10(boolean q10) {
    this.q10 = q10;
}

public boolean isQ11() {
    return q11;
}

public void setQ11(boolean q11) {
    this.q11 = q11;
}

public boolean isQ12() {
    return q12;
}

public void setQ12(boolean q12) {
    this.q12 = q12;
}

public boolean isQ13() {
    return q13;
}

public void setQ13(boolean q13) {
    this.q13 = q13;
}

public boolean isQ14() {
    return q14;
}

public void setQ14(boolean q14) {
    this.q14 = q14;
}

public boolean isQ15() {
    return q15;
}

public void setQ15(boolean q15) {
    this.q15 = q15;
}

public boolean isQ16() {
    return q16;
}

public void setQ16(boolean q16) {
    this.q16 = q16;
}

public boolean isQ17() {
    return q17;
}

public void setQ17(boolean q17) {
    this.q17 = q17;
}

public boolean isQ18() {
    return q18;
}

public void setQ18(boolean q18) {
    this.q18 = q18;
}

public boolean isQ19() {
    return q19;
}

public void setQ19(boolean q19) {
    this.q19 = q19;
}

public boolean isQ20() {
    return q20;
}

public void setQ20(boolean q20) {
    this.q20 = q20;
}
}
```

Above is my POJO class. Now I need to set the recyclerview checkboxes based on the boolean values assigned to the POJO class. In my recyclerview adapter, this POJO class is available.

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class DonorHealthStatusAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DonorHealthStatusAdapter.HealthViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<DonorHealthStatusQuestionare> questionares;
private HealthStatusCheck healthStatusCheck;


public DonorHealthStatusAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DonorHealthStatusQuestionare> questionares,
                                HealthStatusCheck healthStatusCheck) {
    this.context = context;
    this.questionares = questionares;
    this.healthStatusCheck = healthStatusCheck;
}

@Override
public HealthViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_donor_health_info, parent, false);
    return new HealthViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final HealthViewHolder holder, int position) {

    DonorHealthStatusQuestionare questionare = questionares.get(position);
    holder.tv_questions.setText(questionare.getQuestions());

    holder.cbYes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.cbNo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionares.size();
}

public class HealthViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;
    TextView tv_questions;
    CheckBox cbYes, cbNo;

    public HealthViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_health_status_rv);
        tv_questions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_eligibility_question);
        cbYes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxYes);
        cbNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxNo);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You got booleans... you got checkboxes. What else needed?

Comment: I need to set the selection based on boolean values in my recycler view. 20 rows in recycler view. Each row has check boxes which I need to be selected or not selected ..

Comment: Each 20 row has 20 different values. When set selected from my adapter all the check boxes are being selected.

Comment: Simply use `checkbox.setChecked(boolean true or false)`.

Comment: Attach your adapter code.

Comment: Wait a moment. I'm attaching my adapter code.

Comment: I cannot do set checked. Because each row has different values coming from POJO class. Row 1 check box value coming from POJO.isq1 method.

Comment: I have attached adapter code.please check.

Answer (score 1):

Got your point.

Two options -

1) Create another `ArrayList<HealthStatusCheck> answers` and populate rows according to it.
2) *Make a change in webserivce* and get the answer of *Question within the object of Question in Json format*.

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: first option wont work. because there is only one healthstatuscheck object which holds 20 booleans. The webservice cannot return 20 healthstatuscheck object. it returns only one object that has 20 boolean fields. and I think we cannot populate recyclerview by using object fields.

Comment: thinking about what are the changes should i make in webservice. If you have any idea or database design strategy, please share with me.

Comment: my requirement is, in my app I need to ask 20 health-related questions to the user. The user should answer this questions from his profile activity by checking the checkboxes. Ones he has answered the questions, if there is another user searching this user should be able to see these questions as checked or unchecked. any idea

Answer (score 0):

So you have 20 questions which means you have 20 rows, in each row there is two check boxes (they should be either yes or no according to your class model of booleans).

in on bind view holder do this:

```
    @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final HealthViewHolder holder, int position) {

DonorHealthStatusQuestionare questionare = questionares.get(position);
holder.tv_questions.setText(questionare.getQuestions());

 //for question 1 

  holder.cbYes.setChecked(questionare.isQ1());
  holder.cbNo.setChecked(questionare.isQ1());

  //for question 2 

  holder.cbYes.setChecked(questionare.isQ2());
  holder.cbNo.setChecked(questionare.isQ2());


  //for question 3 
  holder.cbYes.setChecked(questionare.isQ3());
  holder.cbNo.setChecked(questionare.isQ3());

  //and so on till you reach the last question (20 in your case)



     }
```

Comment: When assign set checked for the very first time all the check box inside the recycler view will be selected.

Comment: what is the structure of the data source.